# Selenium TimeoutException when trying to click Cookies Agree

Tags: selenium, timeoutexception

I am trying to crawl some articles from a website and before doing so, I need to click the "Cookies Agree" using Selenium in Python.

But unfortunately, I keep getting either TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException!

I've figured out that the click button is within iframe, so I've switched to it and clicked the consent button.

```
homepage = 'link'
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(homepage)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.switch_to.frame('location')

try:
  consent = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'classname')))
  consent.click()
except TimeoutException :
  print('timeoutexception')

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

[iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfi7y.png)

[consent click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgPk8.png)

But still I just can't get through the TimeoutException error.

What have I done wrong....?!

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mess up `wait` and `driver` objects. They are different. Switch to iframe and wait for your button.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


#  switch to frame here

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.message-component.message-button.no-children:nth-of-type(2)')))
consent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.message-component.message-button.no-children:nth-of-type(2)')
consent.click()
```

There are two `.message-component.message-button.no-children` css locators and you need the second one.

To find iframe use (this is bulletproof):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'sp_message_iframe_')]"))
```

Comment: Oh, wow! I had no idea that I was messing up two different objects. People seemed to use them interchangeably, so I just assumed that i could use it like that. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course! But could you help me with the "NoSuchFrameException". After correcting the code, I get "NoSuchFrameException: Message: sp_message_iframe_216133". I didn't get such error before...

Comment: Ok, the locator for the frame is dynamic. I'll help you with it

Comment: And is there any possibility that there's a syntax error in "wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)"? I must have done something wrong, because suddenly I get syntax error...

Comment: Take this as a template:  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (SelectBy.CSS_SELECTOR, "your_css")))

Comment: Be careful with indents. Also check here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:~:text=Selenium%20Webdriver%20provides%20two%20types,trying%20to%20locate%20an%20element.

Comment: Try to wait for iframe first. Then - for your button. It has to work

Comment: For debugging use time.sleep(some amount is seconds)